# String vs Byte string

Tags: python

What's the difference between a string and a byte string?
When is it appropriate to use a byte string instead of a string?

More specifically, if I download an image or another binary file from the web, why do I need to convert it to a byte string before I can save it?

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between `str` and `byte` in Python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.x, there is no difference; `str` is a sequence of bytes.

In 3.x, A byte string is identified by a byte literal, `b'...'`; it can be gotten from a string by encoding it to a specific charset, and it is the default type for most I/O operations.

Comment: Why is it the default type for IO operations?